# Gridview not sorting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I've come across this strange error and it's been bugging me for hours now.

I've got some LinkButtons on my screen and depending on which button the user chooses a label's text is set, a GridView is displayed and the Datasource of this GridView is assigned based on the text of the label.

This all works fine and dandy. However the problem arises when I want to sort this GridView.

At the moment, nothing happens. When I attempt to sort a column the page just refreshes and I'm left with the same unsorted mess in my GridView.

---

I've put my application into debug mode with breakpoints along the way and noticed that when I get to this step (the full code can be seen at the bottom of this post) :

`senderGridView.SortExpression = button.CommandArgument`

the senderGridView.SortExpression is "" so for some reason it's not passing the sort expression.

---

Hopefully somebody can enlighten me as to why my grid isn't sorting as I'm sure it's just a stupid mistake somewhere but any help would be appreciated, thanks.

***Code that you may require...***

My sub that sets the sort images when a row is created can be seen below:

```
Protected Sub GridViewSortImages(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        Dim senderGridView As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)

        'Loop through each cell in header row
        For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            If cell.HasControls Then
                Dim button As LinkButton = TryCast((cell.Controls(0)), LinkButton)
                Dim gv As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
                Dim lnkName As New Label()

                'Test cell to see if a link button exists (i.e. Allow Sorting = True)
                If Not (button Is Nothing) Then

                    'Create new label and image and set to standard unsorted view
                    lnkName.Text = button.Text
                    Dim image As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image
                    image.ImageUrl = "images/sort-1x1.png"
                    image.ToolTip = "Sort"
                    image.AlternateText = "Sort"

                    'Test to see if grid is already sorted, and apply relevant image & tooltip
                    If senderGridView.SortExpression = button.CommandArgument Then
                        If senderGridView.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending Then
                            image.ImageUrl = "images/sort-asc.png"
                            image.ToolTip = "Sort Descending"
                            image.AlternateText = "Sort Descending"
                        Else
                            image.ImageUrl = "images/sort-desc.png"
                            image.ToolTip = "Sort Ascending"
                            image.AlternateText = "Sort Ascending"
                        End If
                    End If

                    'Add label and image to new div
                    gv.Controls.Add(lnkName)
                    gv.Controls.Add(image)

                    'Replace original column header with new div
                    button.Controls.Add(gv)
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

---

My RowCreated sub for the GridView...

```
Protected Sub grvHomeRisk_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grvHomeRisk.RowCreated

        If Not (e.Row Is Nothing) AndAlso e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            GridViewSortImages(sender, e) 'Call sort code
        End If

    End Sub
```

---

My Sorting sub...

```
Protected Sub grvHomeRisk_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles grvHomeRisk.Sorting

        Select Case lblBreachHeaderb.Text
            Case "Current Risks"
                grvHomeRisk.DataSource = SQLDS_ListCurrentRisk
            Case "All Risks Overdue"
                grvHomeRisk.DataSource = SQLDS_ListAllRiskOverdue
            Case "My Risks"
                grvHomeRisk.DataSource = SQLDS_ListMyRisk
            Case "My Risks Overdue"
                grvHomeRisk.DataSource = SQLDS_ListRiskOverdue
            Case "Risks Requested to Score & Re-Score"
                grvHomeRisk.DataSource = SQLDS_ListScores
            Case "Risks Requested to Score"
                grvHomeRisk.DataSource = SQLDS_ListRiskScores
            Case "Risks Requested to Re-Score"
                grvHomeRisk.DataSource = SQLDS_ListRiskReScores
        End Select

            grvHomeRisk.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

---

My GridView...

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvHomeRisk" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"    AllowSorting="true"
    CssClass="GridMain" UseAccessibleHeader="false"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="780px" BorderWidth="0px"
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="IDRISK">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" SelectText="View Risk" ShowSelectButton="True" SelectImageUrl="~/Images/button-select1.png" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TXRISKSUMMARY" HeaderText="Risk" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TSRISKSTART" HeaderText="Start Date" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TSRISKREVIEW" HeaderText="Review Date" SortExpression="TSRISKREVIEW" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TXUSER_NAME_O" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="TXUSER_NAME_O" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TXDESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Risk Element" SortExpression="TXDESCRIPTION" ReadOnly="True"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TSDATMOD" HeaderText="Date Modified" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TXUSER_NAME_M" HeaderText="Modified By" ReadOnly="True" />
                                        </Columns>
                                        <PagerTemplate>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Button ID="FirstButton" runat="server" CommandArgument="First" CommandName="Page" Text="<<" CssClass="buttongrid" ToolTip="First" OnClientClick="needToConfirm = false;" />
                                                        <asp:Button ID="PrevButton" runat="server" CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" Text="Previous" CssClass="button" ToolTip="Previous" OnClientClick="needToConfirm = false;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPageCount" runat="server" CssClass="TextA12Bold" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Button ID="NextButton" runat="server" CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" Text="Next" CssClass="button" ToolTip="Next" OnClientClick="needToConfirm = false;" />
                                                        <asp:Button ID="LastButton" runat="server" CommandArgument="Last" CommandName="Page" Text=">>" CssClass="buttongrid" ToolTip="Last" OnClientClick="needToConfirm = false;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </PagerTemplate>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The fact that you're rebinding the grid to a different datasource in the grvHomeRisk_Sorting event handler might be an issue...

Comment: It isn't binding to a different datasource because the labels text hasn't changed?